# Why does my webform page not detect CSS file?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

No matter what I do it won't detect the css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/customStyles.css" runat="server" />
```

I have tried to place it inside the contentplaceHolder Head both in master page and child page, i tried set path multiple ways,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/CSS/customStyles.css" runat="server" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/customStyles.css" runat="server" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/customStyles.css" runat="server" />
```

Yet nothing works. I also read something about formvalidation and even tried to add on web.config

```
  <location path="CSS">
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

and still nothing... Whhy does it not detect the css file ??

**EDIT**

This is directory

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here's an update, I tried to create a css file on main directory and it worked, so the problem is the css file won't be detected if it's inside a directory...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet1.css" />
```

**EDIT**

Here's what seems to cause the problem

when i go to localhost:port/CSS/customStyles.css only this css appears

```
body {
}
.hidden {
    display:none;
}


.customActive {
    background-color:#cecee8;
}

.ctmHover:hover{
   background-color:#cecee8;
}
```

However the file has all this code

```
body {
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}


.customActive {
    background-color: #cecee8;
}

.ctmHover:hover {
    background-color: #cecee8;
}


.Grid {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
    border: solid 1px #525252;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: Calibri;
    color: #474747;
}

    .Grid td {
        padding: 2px;
        border: solid 1px #c1c1c1;
    }

    .Grid th {
        padding: 4px 2px;
        color: #fff;
        background: #363670 url(Images/grid-header.png) repeat-x top;
        border-left: solid 1px #525252;
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }

    .Grid .alt {
        background: #fcfcfc url(Images/grid-alt.png) repeat-x top;
    }

    .Grid .pgr {
        background: #363670 url(Images/grid-pgr.png) repeat-x top;
    }

        .Grid .pgr table {
            margin: 3px 0;
        }

        .Grid .pgr td {
            border-width: 0;
            padding: 0 6px;
            border-left: solid 1px #666;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 12px;
        }

        .Grid .pgr a {
            color: Gray;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

            .Grid .pgr a:hover {
                color: #000;
                text-decoration: none;
            }


.custom-modal-header {
    background: #b0d4e3; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b0d4e3 0%, #88bacf 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b0d4e3 0%,#88bacf 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b0d4e3 0%,#88bacf 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b0d4e3', endColorstr='#88bacf',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    color: white;
}

.custom-modal-footer {
    background: #b0d4e3; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b0d4e3 0%, #88bacf 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b0d4e3 0%,#88bacf 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b0d4e3 0%,#88bacf 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b0d4e3', endColorstr='#88bacf',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    color: white;
}

.custom-modal-confirm-btn {
    background-color: #98c4d7;
    color: white;
}

    .custom-modal-confirm-btn:hover {
        background-color: #000000;
        color: white;
    }

.custom-modal-cancel-btn {
    font-weight: bold;
}

    .custom-modal-cancel-btn:hover {
        background-color: #6099ca;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

.chkChoice label {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: #142658;
    border-color: #142658;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.chkChoice input {
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: please share your directory structure and how the html is actually generated in the browser.

Comment: why `runat="server"` ? do you need to do anything server side with the css?

Comment: I just tried it from other issues i searched but for me nothing works

Comment: On every test you did, when running your app from the browser, inspect the HTML source, and see what is being rendered there. Also, try to navigate to the file from the web browser, for example: `http://localhost:1234/CSS/customStyles.css` -- If you see any error, please share the error here.

Comment: Just updated, seems like only few css on the file appear and ignores the rest

Answer (score 0):

Please try using base path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath %>/CSS/customStyles.css" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I placed on the content page header and nothing

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a new css file on the same folder and posting the code in there and it worked. I have more code on other CSS file and i checked several times everything is well formatted and I'm still trying to figure out what causes the code to not be read, so as for now the solution is just place the code in a different empty css file

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and looks like the only way is to set an "absolute" path in the scope of the project.
If project looks like this:
[image]

CSS will not load by path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  href="BenchmarsStyles.css">
```

It works only:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  href="/ModelPortfolio/UserControls/BenchmarsStyles.css">
```

Means, it should include all directories from the root of the project.
I hope it helps.